# Outlier for function runtime in R

Tags: r

I am trying to look at system runtime for computationally heavy math functions, but when I run my code I end up with a outlier at n=13.
Wilsons Theorem Runtime in R

[image]

(*I can't upload photos directly yet*)

```
wilson_r <- (function(x) factorial(x-1)%%x==x-1)
  
r_wilson_runtime <- c(1:22)

#R cannot compute `wilson_r(23)` or any $n>22$. As R has a 64 bit limit and $log_2(23!)>64$.

for (x in c(1:22)){
  holder_times <- c(1:10000)
  for (y in c(1:10000)){
    start_time <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    wilson_r(x)
    end_time <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    holder_times[y]<- end_time-start_time
  }
  r_wilson_runtime[x] <-mean(holder_times*(10**6))
}
```

I have tried knitting the document several times, and the outlier remains. Is there a particular reason for the oultier?

Comment: If you run it multiple times, do you always get the same result? I don't. Those are pretty small differences that you are scaling up by a lot.

Comment: I scaled it up because I thought Sys.time was in ms, so scaling it by 10e6 would put nanoseconds as the leading figure. And I've knitted it multiple times (rstudio in an rmd chunk) but the outlier stays the same. And when I run a python version of my code using reticulate, the outlier is not present.

Comment: are you re-knitting the rmd chunk that creates the `r_wilson_runtime` vector or the chunk the prints the plot

Comment: I'm away from my computer. But I believe they are two separate chunks and I re knit them every time I generate a PDF.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WMfoL7F knitting separately and every time. This was another knit.

Answer (score 0):

The result can be sometimes noisy. If it always happens at the same n (be sure knitr is regenerating the whole document) it is just a coincidence. You can easily get rid of the noise (outstanding measurements) in your example by taking a median not mean.

That said, R has a special function system.time, which is designed for measuring time of execution. It is also better to include the inner repetition loop inside of the measurement, like this:

```
wilson_r <- (function(x) factorial(x-1)%%x==x-1)
r_wilson_n = 1:22
r_wilson_runtime = sapply(r_wilson_n, function(x) {
  N = 100000
  ret = system.time({for (y in c(1:N)) wilson_r(x)})
  1e6*ret[1]/N
})
plot(r_wilson_n, r_wilson_runtime)
```

Nevertheless, the result can be still sometimes noisy for such cheap functions (R is a language with automatic gc).

As for your wilson_r for higher n, it is not a good idea to use large integers if you use modulo at the end. It is better to do a modulo at every multiplication. You can use the inline package to make a small C function, to calculate this efficiently:

```
factorial_modulo = inline::cfunction(
  signature(v="integer"),
  " int n=v[0], ret=1, i;
    for (i=2; i<n; i++)
      ret = (ret * i) % n;
    v[0] = ret;",
  convention=".C")
wilson_r <- (function(x) factorial_modulo(x)==x-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try reknitting the pdf and see if there is any funny business with garbage collection. I did see the sys time function, but opted not to use it because it was to the microsecond (I might be off on that), and my RMD is being knitted in a server that runs the function under the time observed. And although I'm slowly a bit spotty on my modular arithmetic, Will taking the modulo of each element in a factorial still produce the same result as factorial then modulo? Thank you once again